# How to get page number dynamically when genration custom TOC in mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf, tableofcontents

I am trying to create custom TOC in mpdf on first page but not sure how to get the page number for dynamic content. Can anyone please help?

```
        $html = '<div class="frame frame-top">
            <div class="mpdf_toc" id="mpdf_toc_0">
    <div class="mpdf_toc_level_0">
        <a class="mpdf_toc_a" href="#__mpdfinternallink_1">
            <span class="mpdf_toc_t_level_0">Section 1</span>
        </a>
        <dottab outdent="2em" />
        <a class="mpdf_toc_a" href="#__mpdfinternallink_1">
            <span class="mpdf_toc_p_level_0">5</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mpdf_toc_level_1">
        <a class="mpdf_toc_a" href="#__mpdfinternallink_2">
            <span class="mpdf_toc_t_level_1">Chapter 1</span>
        </a>
        <dottab outdent="2em" />
        <a class="mpdf_toc_a" href="#__mpdfinternallink_2">
            <span class="mpdf_toc_p_level_1">5</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mpdf_toc_level_2">
        <a class="mpdf_toc_a" href="#__mpdfinternallink_3">
            <span class="mpdf_toc_t_level_2">Topic 1</span>
        </a>
        <dottab outdent="2em" />
        <a class="mpdf_toc_a" href="#__mpdfinternallink_3">
            <span class="mpdf_toc_p_level_2">5</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, pages are determined during putting the document together when the `Output()` method is called and the content is finalized.